# How much is the insurance contribution of inbound travel insurance for Thailand

Tags: visas, covid-19, thailand, insurance

This is related to the new [STV granted from Thailand and required](https://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand-visa/special-tourist-visa-thailand) for this Visa (see red link on page).

Every report with experience by that is much appreciated.

Comment: to mention is : I get 60 soon , would travel then from India to Thailand...

Comment: Are you asking how much the required policy costs or how much it should cover?

Comment: Note that the site you linked to is not an official Thai government website. Also note that several sources state that the STV is targeted at people from "low-risk countries". I haven't found the current list, but given the current situation, I doubt India is considered low-risk or will remain so if it still is. Also the embassy and visa application centre in New Delhi are currently closed, don't know about the other locations.

Comment: Voted to reopen, the question is 100% clear.

Comment: @JJJ
how much is the insurance contribution

Comment: What do you mean by "insurance contribution?" What insurance pays depends on what kind of claim is tendered. What does the policy _say_ about coverage? Have you asked the business that's selling the policy?

Comment: my question is clear: of course I mean what I heave to pay.  insurer never give information about it.

Comment: How is this not a shopping question? Even if it not, the quote is based on things like country of origin, age of insured and length of stay. In other words, you would need someone going to Thailand from India, who is your age, and is staying for the same length of time. I propose, submit a request for a quote, and then you'll know.

Answer (score 3):

> I [...] would travel from India to Thailand. – [Asklep](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43356/asklep) [6 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163625/how-much-is-an-inbound-travel-insurance-for-thailand/163630#comment411675_163625)

It's currently not possible to travel from India to Thailand. See https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/2105951/thailand-bans-travel-from-india:

> Thailand will close its border to travellers from India, except Thai citizens, beginning on Saturday, the Thai embassy in New Delhi announced on Monday.

Thai certificates of entry issued for people flying from India to Thailand also have been cancelled.

Thailand is currently experiencing its third and by far most severe covid-19 wave: it has increased its travel restrictions and tries to avoid getting the Indian covid-19 variant. A third of Thai provinces have night curfews, and there are other limitations (e.g., in Bangkok: no dine-in restaurants, bars/clubs are closed, and malls have limited opening hours).

Comment: It's probably still possible to travel via a third country. So to go from India to a third country and stay there for a few weeks. Then apply for a Thai COE and visa from that country. Of course that is a lot of work as you'll still have to quarantine in Thailand (and possibly in the third country as well). On the flip side, Thailand is still considered safe by the EU, so when you move on from there you may be able to skip mandatory quarantine in the EU (if it's still considered safe then and only in certain EU countries which follow the exemption list).

Comment: @JJJ thanks, yes of course, hopping is pretty much always ok. Unsure for how long one could skip mandatory quarantine in the EU (if that's still possible), 3rd wave is pretty bad.

Comment: They're still on [(the Dutch adaptation of?) the EU safe list](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/eu-list-of-safe-countries). That allows free entry (no test, no quarantine) to the Netherlands and some other but not all (e.g. Belgium) EU countries. I don't have a comprehensive list but I know some more countries have exceptions (don't follow the list at all or only partial adherence). But yeah, I think they've pretty much lost control now and I personally wouldn't consider it safe anymore (which I did pre-Songkran).

Comment: @JJJ likewise, Songkran was the turning point.